# Retrieve multiple elements with "getElementById"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried using the techniques mentioned [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304497/javascript-multiple-getelementbyids-in-one-call) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709537/multiple-id-in-getelementbyid) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607291/javascript-and-getelementbyid-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id), but I haven't had any luck. I'm trying to adjust a JavaScript function to retrieve multiple divs using the `getElementById` method.

Here is the current line of code within the function which retrieves the div `#cat1`:

```
  var elem = document.getElementById(cat1);
```

Moving forward, I need this function to also retrieve the div `#cat2`.

jQuery can be loaded if there's a better method to accomplish this using their library?

---

Here is the full function (*reference Line 3*):

```
function getCategories(initial) {
  var i;
  var elem = document.getElementById('cat1');
  if (initial == 1) {
  jsonGroups = "";
  jsonGroups = '{ xml: [], "pin": [] ';
  for (i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (elem.childNodes[i].nodeName == "LI") {
      jsonGroups = jsonGroups + ',  "' + elem.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value + '": [] ';
    }
  }
  jsonGroups = jsonGroups + "}";
  markerGroups = eval('(' + jsonGroups + ')');

for (i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (elem.childNodes[i].nodeName == "LI") {
        var elemID = elem.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;
        if (elemID != "user") {
          elem.childNodes[i].innerHTML = "<a onclick='" + 'toggleGroup("' + elemID + '")' + "'>" + elem.childNodes[i].innerHTML + "</a>";
        } else {
          elem.childNodes[i].innerHTML = '<form id="userPOIForm" action="#" onsubmit="userPOIFind(this.userPOI.value); return false"><input id="userPOITxt" size="20" name="userPOI" value="' + elem.childNodes[i].innerHTML + '" type="text"><input id="userPOIButton" value="Go" type="submit"> </form>';

        }
        if (hasClass(elem.childNodes[i], "hidden") !== null) {
          elem.childNodes[i].setAttribute("caption", "hidden");
        } else {
          elem.childNodes[i].setAttribute("caption", "");
        }
        if (elem.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem("caption").value != "hidden") {
          classAdder = document.getElementById(elemID);
          addClass(classAdder, "visibleLayer");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (elem.childNodes[i].nodeName == "LI") {
        var catType = elem.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;
        
      result = doSearch(elem.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem("title").value, elem.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `.attributes.getNamedItem("id").value` can be replaced with `.id`...

Comment: why not use `jsonGroups` as an object not string? Can always convert to string with `JSON.stringify` if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to select all elements with an `id` that starts with `cat`, you can do this in jQuery like this:

```
$("[id^=cat]")
```

[jQuery: Attributes Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Also note that there are many other ways in which your code can be shortened by leveraging jQuery's utility methods. Things like `$("[id^=cat]".children.each(function() { $(this).prop("caption", "hidden"})` come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

Just make `categoriesList` be another parameter, and call the function twice.